# If $X_1, \dots , X_n \sim U[0,\theta]$ and iid. Verify that the distribution function of $X_n$

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

We know that $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are $ U[0,\theta ]$ and iid. I'm told to recall that the sufficient statistics and also maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ is $X_{(n)}=\max\{X_1, \dots, X_n\}$

Then I have to verify that the distribution function of $X_{(n)}$ is

$$F_{X_{(n)}}(y\mid \theta)= P(X_{(n)} \leq y)=\left(\frac{y}{\theta}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}I\{0 \leq y \leq \theta\} + I\{y > \theta\}$$

I'm the worst when it comes to the uniform distribution and these kinds of things so can anyone offer any advice. I tried taking the product from 1 to n so I would get the $\left(\frac{y}{\theta}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}$ but I can't figure out where the indicator functions come from.

Answer (score 1):

The $X_i$ are uniform on $[0,\theta]$. Let $Y$ be the maximum of the $X_i$.

Then $Y\le y$ if and only if all the $X_i$ are $\le y$. For an individual $i$, we have, for $0\le y\le \theta$ 
$$\Pr(X_i\le y=\frac{y}{\theta}.$$
Thus, for $0\le y\le \theta$,
$$F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\left(\frac{y}{\theta}\right)^n.$$

We also have $F_Y(y)=0$ if $y\lt 0$, and $F_Y(y)=1$ if $y\gt \theta$.

The indicator function stuff is meant to gather the three cases $y\lt 0$, $0\le y\le \theta$, and $y\gt \theta$ into a single formula.

The first multiplication by $I_{0\le y\le \theta}$ multiplies by $1$ on $[0,\theta]$ and by $0$ outside this interval. So it gives the right answer for $y\lt 0$ and also for $0\le y\le \theta$.

But it produces $0$ for $y\gt \theta$, and we want $1$ there. That's fixed by adding $I_{y\gt \theta}$.

Comment: So then would the density function of $X_{n}$ just be f_{X_{n}}(y|\theta)=(\frac{1}{\theta})^{n}I\{0 \leq y \leq \theta\}+I\{y>\theta}$

Comment: In the interesting part, the derivative is $\frac{n}{\theta^n}y^{n-1}$. And we don't want the $I_{y\gt \theta}$ part, the derivative of that is $0$.

Comment: So then that would completely change the mean and variance?